# Can you use user-defined Models as SchemaTypes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I have a `User` Schema defined like so:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  validSpotTypes: [String]
});

module.exports = UserSchema;
```

I also defined a `PendingRideRequest` Schema like so:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const PendingRideRequestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  requester: {
    email: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    validSpotTypes: [String]
  },
  dateTime: Date,
  location: {
    lat: Number,
    lng: Number
  },
  parkingLot: String,
  spotType: String
});

module.exports = PendingRideRequestSchema;
```

**My Question:** Can I replace `requester`'s body with `UserSchema`?

Example:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('./user');

const PendingRideRequestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  requester: User, //<-- Like this
  dateTime: Date,
  location: {
    lat: Number,
    lng: Number
  },
  parkingLot: String,
  spotType: String
});

module.exports = PendingRideRequestSchema;
```

*Note: I do not plan to add user-sensitive information like `password` into the `PendingRideRequest` model. However, I would just like to know if using a user-defined Model as a SchemaType is possible, to make my code less redundant.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can , by referencing the schema .

But this is a very simple issue , you should have looked it up before as it's in 
[mongoose docs.](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)
Anyway,

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  validSpotTypes: [String]
});

const PendingRideRequestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  requester: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
  dateTime: Date,
  location: {
    lat: Number,
    lng: Number
  },
  parkingLot: String,
  spotType: String
});
```

**PS**: You should use populate to fill the "requester" field with data before accessing it otherwise it will just return the "ID" of the "User" linked to it (as a requester).

Hope this helps ?

Comment: I think requester field in PendingRideRequestSchema doesn't need to be an array.